# Efficiences of using ng-class-odd?

Tags: angularjs

Is it better to use

```
ul li:nth-child(odd){}
ul li:nth-child(even){}
```

instead of ng-class-odd and ng-class-even ?

i.e is it more efficient to use css than javascript for alternate coloration of rows in a "ul" list

My list has anywhere between 30-200 rows

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR: `ng-class-odd`/`ng-class-even` are nicer, albeit worse performing and give less specific control than CSS. If you can use `ng-class-odd`/`ng-class-even`, do.**

**On performance:**

Raw CSS should always be faster than AngularJS' evaluation of an expression because the browser has to evaluate styles for elements as the DOM changes regardless. Evaluating `ng-class-odd`/`ng-class-even` attributes is extra computation to generate these computed attribute values.

**In the real world:**

`ng-class-even` and `ul li:nth-child(odd){}` are not exactly the same thing. `ng-class-even` is in terms of the `ng-repeat` but with the selector `ng-class-even` you can be independent of it - you can apply a more specific selector if you like. Want to not do this to the first item? You will need CSS.

This seems to be a trade off between elegance, performance and control.

Unless you are looking at thousands and thousands of rows, performance is a non-issue and you should write code that looks nice to people. *Of course, I would love to see some hard statistics on performance differences here for this extreme use case!*

**For elegance but less control and less performance, don't tie your CSS to `ng-repeat` and use `ng-class-even`.**

For performance and control (but less elegance), use CSS and not `ng-class-even`.